# Performance benefits of static typing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is there any performance benefits of using static typing in Objective-C? Does it exist just for safety check?

Comment: There is no static typing in objc, everything is dynamic. If
 you want a static language, use C++.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Is it true?  The typing disciplines in Objective-C are : Static, Dynamic and Weak as per Apple Documentation. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Chandu to the runtime, everything is just an object, it has no concept of "type". You can cast the pointer to whatever type you want (aside from maybe a block), and it will still call the correct method implementation based on the class. Now, some of this has gotten stricter with ARC, but for the most part, the only "static" part of the language is done as a warning at compile time, and can be fixed with a cast that can *never* fail at runtime, unlike a 'true' static language like Java and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's for safety checks only.

Objective-C messages (method invocations) are always dynamically dispatched at runtime. Adding additional static type information will help the compiler warn you of errors, but (for the most part) has no effect on the code generated. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Dynamic_typing

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the compiler?

Comment: It's not completely true that static typing has no effect on generated code. It is possible for multiple, identical selectors to return different types. In this case, static typing of the receiver determines the particular flavor of objc_msgsend() to use, like objc_msgsend_stret() or objc_msgsend_fpret().

Comment: @Gabe Nope -- by definition, a correctly written Objective-C compiler will always dispatch every method call through the runtime's dispatch mechanism.   A compiler may have some kind of extension that breaks that requirement, but it would no longer be a conforming ObjC compiler.

Comment: @bbum: That's interesting. Even utterly dynamic languages like JavaScript allow for this sort of optimization, so I figured a compile-ahead-of-time language like Objective-C would permit it.

Comment: A method's implementation can be changed at any time via a category load or swizzling (or, historically, posing).   Thus, no such optimization is possible while preserving the absolutely dynamic nature of Objective-C [without incurring massive potential overhead in either CPU or binary size].